# How to Get % Difference Between Values in a pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df of the form:

```py
    Date       Cost
1   29.01.21   100
2   28.01.21   120
3   27.01.21   110
4   ...
```

I want to add a column called `Differential` which calculates the difference in cost between any given number of days (rows). As an example, for a differential between 3 days (row 1 to row 3) the above would become:

```py
    Date       Cost   Differential
1   29.01.21   100    -10%
2   28.01.21   120
3   27.01.21   110
4   ...
```

Where -10% is `(100 - 110)/ 100`. I know this is achievable with a `For` loop, which is what I have tried below, but **is there a smarter and faster way to do this**?

```py
num_days = 3
for row in range(df.shape[0]):
    df.iloc[2, row] = (df.iloc[1, row] - df.iloc[1, row + num_days]) / df.iloc[1, row]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative shift like so, where x is your desired number of rows.

```
df['differential'] = (df['Cose'] - df['Cost'].shift(-x)) / 100
```

For exmaple to shift by three rows

```
df['differential'] = (df['Cose'] - df['Cost'].shift(-3)) / 100
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.Series.pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html):

```
>>> n = 3
>>> df.assign(Differential=df['Cost'].pct_change(n-1).shift(-(n-1)).mul(-100))
       Date  Cost  Differential
1  29.01.21   100         -10.0
2  28.01.21   120           NaN
3  27.01.21   110           NaN
```

As you are viewing 2 rows in future, the last two rows will be NaN

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were expecting?

```
days = 3
df.join(df.loc[::-1,'Cost'].pct_change(periods=days-1),rsuffix=('_Pct Change'))
```